# Get gofile.me through command line - Synology

Tags: synology

I am writing a small module in PHP that will send emails to my customers (using PHPMailer).

I do not want to attach huge files to those emails but rather publish a link to download the files (Zipped).

The files are stored on a Synology under DSM6.x.

Is there a way through the command line in SSH to point to the desired files and generate the gofile.me link using Synology instructions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible via [Synology REST API](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf).

Although maybe this is not exactly what you want, here's a Python 3 script for creating `gofile.me` links from command line. Unfortunately, I was failed to find any simple working solutions in the Internet, so I wrote it by myself. Hope this helps ([see also my Github repo](https://github.com/ded32/SynoShare)).

```
#=========================================================================
# SynoShare.py                                               (c) Ded, 2020
#=========================================================================
#
# Creates a public http://gofile.me link for path/file located on Synology server.
#
# Usage: SynoShare.py <path / filename_to_share> [--debug]
#
# Copyright (c) 2020. Ded (Ilya Dedinsky, mail@ded32.ru)
#=========================================================================

from __future__ import print_function;
import requests;
import json;
import traceback;
import sys;
import os;

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# These values are imported from OS environment variables to avoid exposing of private data:
#
# SynoShareNAS     - Synology NAS IP or DNS name
# SynoShareAccount - Synology NAS Account used for creating links
# SynoSharePasswd  - Synology NAS Account password
#
# Set these variables BEFORE calling this script. They may be crypted, see below.
#
# NOTE: This script contains Decode() function for decoding login data, which may be crypted.
# Now this function works transparently, simply returning its parameters. You can update this
# function to support your scheme of encrypting login credentials.
#-------------------------------------------------------------

NAS     = str (os.getenv ("SynoShareNAS"));
Account = str (os.getenv ("SynoShareAccount"));
Passwd  = str (os.getenv ("SynoSharePasswd"));

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Exit codes of the script
#-------------------------------------------------------------

LinkCreated    = 0;
LinkExists     = 1;
LinkNotCreated = 2;
FatalError     = 3;
SyntaxError    = 255;

#-------------------------------------------------------------

Sid = "";

Debug = False;
if (len (sys.argv) >= 3): Debug = (sys.argv[2] == "--debug");

#-------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    _("", "main()");

    global Debug;
    if (len (sys.argv) >= 3): Debug = (sys.argv[2] == "--debug");

    file = "";
    if (len (sys.argv) >= 2): file = sys.argv[1];

    if (file == ""):
        eprint ("ERROR: Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " <path/filename to share> [--debug]");
        return SyntaxError;

    if (NAS == "None" or Account == "None" or Passwd == "None"):
        eprint ("ERROR: SynoShareNAS, SynoShareAccount or SynoSharePasswd environment variable(s) NOT found");
        return SyntaxError;

    DoAuth (Account, Passwd);

    list = SharingList();

    links = list["data"]["links"];
    total = list["data"]["total"];

    for (link) in (links):
        if (link["path"] == file):
            url = _(link["url"], "url");

            eprint ("EXISTS:", url);
            print (url);
            return LinkExists;

    url  = "";
    link = _(SharingCreate (file), "link");

    if (link["success"] == True):
        url = _(link["data"]["links"][0]["url"], "url");

        eprint ("CREATED:", url);
        print (url);
        return LinkCreated;

    else:
        eprint ("NOT created:", '"' + file + '"');
        return LinkNotCreated;

#=========================================================================

def GetApiInfo():
    _("\n", "GetApiInfo()");

    return _(Get ("query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query&query=SYNO.API.Auth,SYNO.FileStation"), "GetApiInfo");

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

def DoAuth (account, passwd):
    _("\n" + "account = " + account + ", passwd = " + passwd, "DoAuth()");

    try:
        account = Decode (account);
        passwd  = Decode (passwd);

        res = _(Get ("auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=3&method=login&account=" + account + "&passwd=" + passwd + "&session=FileStation&format=sid"), "DoAuth()");

        global Sid;
        Sid = res["data"]["sid"];

        return _(Sid, "DoAuth(): Sid");

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception ('DoAuth(): Cannot auth in "' + NAS + '":\n  ' + str (e));

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

def SharingList():
    _("\n", "SharingList()");

    return _(Get ("entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Sharing&version=3&method=list"), "DoSharing");

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

def SharingCreate (path):
    _("\n" + "path = " + path, "SharingCreate()");

    return _(Get ('entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Sharing&version=3&method=create&path="' + path + '"'), "DoSharing");

#=========================================================================

def Get (request):
    _("\n" + "request = " + request, "Get()");

    if (Sid != ""): request += "&_sid=" + Sid;

    res = _(requests.get (_("http://" + NAS + "/webapi/" + request, "GET")), "GET");
    if (res.status_code != 200):  raise Exception ("Get (" + request + "): Bad status " + str (res.status_code) + ":\n  " + res.text);

    res = json.loads (res.text);
    if (not res["success"]): raise Exception ("Get (" + request + "):\n" + "  Error: " + StrError (res["error"]["code"]));

    return _(res, "GOT");

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

def StrError (code):

    errlist = { 400: "No such account or incorrect password",
                401: "Account disabled",
                402: "Permission denied",
                403: "2-step verification code required",
                404: "Failed to authenticate 2-step verification code",
               2000: "Sharing link does not exist",
               2001: "Cannot generate sharing link because too many sharing links exist",
               2002: "Failed to access sharing links" };

    return str (code) + ": " + errlist.get (code, "Unknown error");

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

def Decode (str):
    _("str = " + str, "Decode()");

#   TODO: add some transformation code here to avoid expose your account name and passwd

    return str;

#=========================================================================

def _ (data = "", name = ""):

    if (not Debug): return data;

    if (str (data) [0:1] == "\n"): data = data[1:]; eprint();

    if (name != ""): eprint (name, ": ", sep = "", end = "");

    if (data != ""): eprint ('"', data, '"', sep = "");
    else: eprint();

    return data;

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

def eprint (*args, **kwargs):

    print (*args, file = sys.stderr, **kwargs);

#=========================================================================

try:
    sys.exit (main());

except Exception as e:

    eprint ("ERROR: " + str (e));
    if (Debug): eprint ("\n" + traceback.format_exc());
    sys.exit (FatalError);

#=========================================================================
```

Comment: How do you use this? I'm getting ERROR: .SynoShareNAS, .SynoShareAccount or .SynoSharePasswd environment variable(s) NOT found errors.

Comment: With the browser I managed to authenticated with the api. But when I change the values for NAS/user/passwd in the script to what worked in the browser, I get errors.

Comment: I managed to get my account authorized but now I'm getting errors when trying to share a link to a file. I'm doing `python3 test.py3  %2Fvar%2Fservices%2Fhomes%2Fadmin%2Fblah` and every conceivable way of doing it but keep getting 407 and 408 errors.

Comment: Finally figured it out. The file paths are relative to the File Station. So if you have a folder in file station called "backup" and a file in "backup" call "blah.txt", the path to the file is `/backup/blah.txt`

Comment: StevieD, thanks for clarification, I've updated the help.