# Unable to generate a share link via a script and Synology API

Tags: python, api, synology

I'm hitting a wall with the python script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946539/1641112. I've added the script to a file called `test.py3`.

I'm running this command directly on my Synology drive with an admin account: `python test.py3 /volume2/dir/key-basic-preferred.pdf --debug`

The relevant part of the debug output:

```
Get(): "request = entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Sharing&version=3&method=create&path="/volume2/dir/key-basic-preferred.pdf""
GET: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Sharing&version=3&method=create&path="/volume2/dir/key-basic-preferred.pdf"&_sid=011o6xaJaxvLsKCJ4N91278"
GET: "<Response [200]>"
ERROR: Get (entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Sharing&version=3&method=create&path="/volume2/dir/key-basic-preferred.pdf"&_sid=011o6xaJaxvLsKCJ4N91278):
  Error: 408: Unknown error
```

The 408 error is an unknown file according to the [API docs](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf).

However, I know that file exists. I've tried URL encoding the path. I've tried with and without quotes. I've tried noodling with the python code (don't know python) to change the quotations and api version to 1 instead of 3 but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The file paths are relative to the File Station. So if you have a folder in file station called "backup" and a file in "backup" call "blah.txt", the path to the file is `/backup/blah.txt`